# Find out All the Line Numbers of a Word from Text

Tags: java, hashmap

I wrote a method and it has to find all line numbers of word and then print them.
Input must be following

```
 Word:works/*(just one in file)*/Line Number:[7]  
 Word:run                      Line Number:[3,7,9]
 Word:we                       Line Number[5,8]
```

And that's my method

```
HashMap m2 = new HashMap();

public void addLine(FileReader file) throws IOException {
        try {
            LineNumberReader lnR = new LineNumberReader(file);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = lnR.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                String[] words = line.split("\\W+");
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    if (m2.get(words[i].toLowerCase()) == null) {
                        m2.put(words[i].toLowerCase(), "[" + lnR.getLineNumber() + " ");
                    } else {
                        int x = lnR.getLineNumber();
                        m2.put(words[i].toLowerCase(), " " + x + "]");
                    }
                }
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = lnR.readLine();
            }
            lnR.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + file + "'");
        }
    }
```

And my main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
addLine(new FileReader("C:/Users/Text.txt"));
Map<String, String> sorted1 = new TreeMap<String, String>(m2);
        for (Object key : sorted1.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Word: " + key + "\tLine Number: " m2.get(key));
        }
}
```

My method gives me wrong output.

```
Word: write     Line Number:  [9
Word: we    Line Number:  8]
```

How can I fix that problem ?
Thanks to all readers.

Comment: Please add the contents of `C:/Users/Text.txt`

Comment: Contents of file are just word and punctuation.We can think of a short story or any article. @MPirious

Comment: Please post code that compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some small changes:

(Not mandatory: Save the lower-cased word instead of doing it four times.)

```
final String lowerCaseWord = words[i].toLowerCase();
```

If the word is not in the HashMap, add the square bracket and the line number.

```
if (m2.get(lowerCaseWord) == null) {
    m2.put(lowerCaseWord, "[" + lnR.getLineNumber());
} [...]
```

If the word is in the HashMap, **get the stored value and append** the new line number.

```
[...] else {
    int x = lnR.getLineNumber();
    m2.put(lowerCaseWord, m2.get(lowerCaseWord) + "," + x);
}
```

Add all closing square brackets.

```
for (String key : m2.keySet()) {
    m2.put(key, m2.get(key) + ']');
}
```

Edit:

For this to work, you need to declare m2 as:

```
static Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
static Map<String, List<Integer>> addLine(Reader reader) {
    LineNumberReader r = new LineNumberReader(reader);
    return r.lines()
        .filter(line -> line.length() != 0)
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\W+")))
        .map(word -> word.toLowerCase())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word,
            TreeMap::new,
            Collectors.mapping(word -> r.getLineNumber(), Collectors.toList())));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (Reader reader = new FileReader("C:/Users/Text.txt")) {
        for (Entry<String, List<Integer>> e : addLine(reader).entrySet())
            System.out.println("Word: " + e.getKey() + "\tLine Number: " + e.getValue());
    }
}
```